# spatial partitioning algorithms for 1D dataset?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, partitioning, dbscan, bigdata

[image: Area divided into 10000 squares and data set has traffic vol per sq]

This is Grid which represents geographical area in 10,000 squares, where each square is 55225 square meter.

The dataset has the traffic volume per square raning from 100 to 1000.

for ex:

square 1 - 100,

square 2 - 500

.

.

Square 10,000 - 800

Now, I want to partition this area in such a way that each partition may have different area but will carry similar amount of traffic, standard deviation of traffic among partitions should be minimum.Any suggestion for the spatial partition algorithm?

Comment: There are a few decisions you have to make in order to inform your procedure. The `first question` that comes to mind is if the number of partitions is defined? The `second question` is if there are any geometric restrictions on a group, i.e. must they be contiguous, or is any particular shape ideal? The `third question` is regarding how good is good enough? There is often a huge difference in the run time of an algorithm that provides an ideal answer (perhaps a greedy algorithm) and an algorithm that provides an optimal answer (perhaps an exhaustive or "brute force" approach).

Comment: kpie thanks for your response.Pls find my ans to questions:

The number of partitions is needed around 500 to 600.

They must be contiguous, but they can vary in size..since this partition is for telecom networks it can be either circular or hexagonal.

In this case good means lets say if we have 500 partitions all those partitions should carry similar amount of traffic. i.e the total traffic for these 10000 squares distributed uniformly among 500 partitions.

Comment: So you don't just have a grid, you have a 100 by 100 square grid?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: If you send some sample data over I can debug and test my solution, I wrote it in python using a greedy algorithm. Also I noticed that you are in Italy so you probably don't Venmo... You can find all my personal information here https://krewn.github.io and we can use whatever payment method suits you best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few decisions you have to make in order to inform your procedure. The `first question` that comes to mind is if the number of partitions is defined? The `second question` is if there are any geometric restrictions on a group, i.e. must they be contiguous, or is any particular shape ideal? The `third question` is regarding how good is good enough? There is often a huge difference in the run time of an algorithm that provides an ideal answer (perhaps a greedy algorithm) and an algorithm that provides an optimal answer (perhaps an exhaustive or "brute force" approach). You will get a minimum standard deviation by grouping any 2 sectors that have the same volume, as your groups will will each have 0 standard deviation. Any way, this sounds a lot like a expanded `bin packing problem` and you should probably start your literature review there.

You need to pack your bins in order...

Here I selected center points for my circles biased on the highest traffic flow and filled them in from there.

```
class trafficNode:
    def __init__(self,v,i):
        self.cluster = None
        self.value = v
        self.index = i
        self.occupied = False
    def occupy(self):
        self.occupied=True

def tryAdd(xList,mList,irow,icol):
    try:
        if not(mList[irow][icol] in xList and !mList[irow][icol].occupied):
            xlist.append(mList[irow][icol])
    except IndexError:
        chill = None
    return(xlist)

class cluster:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = []
    def getTotal(self):
        total = 0
        for k in self.nodes:
            total += k.value
        return(total)
    def addNode(self,n):
        self.nodes.append(n)
    def getNeighbors(self,m,r = 0):
        neighbors = []
        for k in self.nodes:
            i = k.index()
            for k2 in range(0,4):
                if k2==0:
                    neighbors = tryAdd(neighbors,m,i[0]+0,i[1]+1)
                elif k2==1:
                    neighbors = tryAdd(neighbors,m,i[0]+1,i[1]+0)
                elif k2==2:
                    neighbors = tryAdd(neighbors,m,i[0]+0,i[1]-1)
                elif k2==3:
                    neighbors = tryAdd(neighbors,m,i[0]-1,i[1]+0)
                if r != 0:
                    if k2==0:
                        neighbors = tryAdd(neighbors,m,i[0]+1,i[1]+1)
                    elif k2==1:
                        neighbors = tryAdd(neighbors,m,i[0]+1,i[1]-1)
                    elif k2==2:
                        neighbors = tryAdd(neighbors,m,i[0]-1,i[1]+1)
                    elif k2==3:
                        neighbors = tryAdd(neighbors,m,i[0]-1,i[1]-1)
        return(neighbors)
    def seed(self,m,irow,icol):
        self.nodes.append(m[irow][icol])
        m[irow][icol].occupy()
    def propogate(self,m,target):
        total = 0
        for k in self.nodes:
            total += k.value
        s = 1
        while total<target:
            s = 1 if !s else 0
            lastTotal=Total
            n = self.getNeighbors(m,s)
            if len(n==0):
                break;
            else:
                if(abs(target-(total+sum([k.value for k in n])))<abs(target-total)):
                    for k in n:
                        self.nodes.append(k)
                        m[k.index[0]][k.index[1]].occupy()
                else:
                    break;
    def contains(self,i):
        ret = False
        for k in self.nodes 
            if k.index == i
                ret = False
                break;
        return(ret)

def parseData(d,s): # Where d is the source datafile and s is the number of units per row.
    ret = []
    f = open(d,"r")
    text = f.read()
    lines = f.split("\n")
    n = 0
    r = 0
    temp = []
    for k in lines:
        v = k.split(" - ")[1]
        n+=1
        temp.append(trafficNode(v,(r,n)))
        if n == s:
            n = 0
            r += 1
            ret.append(temp)
            temp = []
    return(ret)

def mapTotal(m):
    return sum([sum([k2.value for k2 in k]) for k in m])

def pTotal(m,n):
    return(mapTotal/n)

import sys

infile = sys.argv[1]
ncols = sys.argv[2]
ntowers = sys.argv[3]
m = parseData(infile,ncols)
s = pTotal(m,ntowers)

spots = [k.index for k in m if !k.occupied]
clusters = []
while len(spots > 0):
    spotVals = [m[k[0]][k[1]].value for k in spots]
    nextSpotIndex = spots[spotVals.index(max(spotVals))]
    clusters.append(cluster)
    clusters[n].seed(self,m,nextSpotIndex[0],nextSpotIndex[1])
    clusters[n].propogate(m,s)
    spots = [k.index for k in m if !k.occupied]
```

That said I haven't tested it yet... Does your data come as that image or another file?

Comment: Actually, I tried bin packing approach and almost my problem is solvable using this approach. 

I am giving traffic volume  in (100 X 100 matrix) as input to first-fit algorithm, the algorithm will read input row by row from matrix and it forms bin but the mostly I will get the straight line or rectangular as a bin shape but in my case desirable bin shape is square/circular or hexagonal. Also, the bins should accommodate contiguous squares but with this approach I am not getting contiguous bins/clusters. Any inputs on it how to deal with this?